# : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps scala.Predef$.refArrayOps(java.lang.Object[])'

Tags: java, scala, pyspark, dbscan

I was trying to implement the DBSCAN model in PySpark framework. [Github link of complete implementation](https://github.com/SalilJain/pyspark_dbscan) . I just copied and run the code from 'README.md' segment. The code is

```
import dbscan
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

from pyspark.sql import types as T, SparkSession

from scipy.spatial import distance

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("DBSCAN") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.3-s_2.11") \
        .config('spark.driver.host', '127.0.0.1') \
        .getOrCreate()
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=750, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.4, random_state=5)
data = [(i, [float(item) for item in X[i]]) for i in range(X.shape[0])]
schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType(), False),
                               T.StructField("value", T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()), False)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df_clusters = dbscan.process(spark, df, .2, 10, distance.euclidean, 2, "checkpoint")
```

which shows me the error message as

```
-
```

**> --------------------------------------------------------------------------

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>
> in ()
> 12                                T.StructField("value", T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()), False)])
> 13 df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
> ---> 14 df_clusters = dbscan.process(spark, df, .2, 10, distance.euclidean, 2, "checkpoint")
>
> 4 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in
> get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
> 327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
> --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
> 329             else:
> 330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o185.createGraph. :
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps
> scala.Predef$.refArrayOps(java.lang.Object[])'    at
> org.graphframes.GraphFrame$.apply(GraphFrame.scala:676)   at
> org.graphframes.GraphFramePythonAPI.createGraph(GraphFramePythonAPI.scala:10)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)**

I really don't know anything on Java or scala ; also beginner at pyspark . Kindly help me to solve out this problem , I need it badly!

Comment: What versions of everything did you install?

Comment: Can you show the python code that caused this error?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I ran the code at Google  Colab.

Comment: @user ,Sir kindly visit to the attached link , I just run the code at 'README.md' segment.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I ran the code at Google  Colab. I installed pyspark by pip command so I think it is 3.0.1 version  and graphframes version 0.6.

Comment: @user Now I have attached the code here

Comment: Does Colab come with some version of Java and Scala already? Your error is related to a Scala version issue, not Spark

Comment: Also notice that your package needs Spark 2.3 **and** scala 2.11 ... `spark2.3-s_2.11`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops